# "too much recursion" in my rotating banner script

Tags: javascript, jquery

My rotating banner script is throwing a "Too much recursion" error when the `iKeyless.widget.Rotator.rotate();` function is called within `init();`.  I can't figure out why, `init();` is only called once and there's a defer() on the second call.... when the page loads it lags before throwing "too much recursion"

```
    return {
        init: function () {
            ui.container = $("#rotating-banner");
            ui.thumbs = $("#rotating-banner .tabs .tab");
            ui.banners = $("#rotating-banner .banner");
            ui.fadeBox = $(".rotate .bd .fade-box");

            ui.thumbs.each(function (idx, el) {
                $(el).click(function () {
                    paused = true;

                    iKeyless.widget.Rotator.rotate.show(idx);
                });
            });

            iKeyless.widget.Rotator.rotate();
        },
        show: function (idx) {
            ui.fadeBox.css("display", "block");
            ui.fadeBox.animate({
                opacity: 1
            },
            .125,
            function () {
                $('.active', $(ui.banners[idx]).addClass('active').parent()).removeClass('active');

                ui.fadeBox.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                },
                .125,
                function () {
                    ui.fadeBox.css("display", "none");
                });
            });
        },
        rotate: function () {
            if (!paused) {
                this.show(counter);

                counter = counter + 1;

                if (counter === ui.thumbs.length) {
                    counter = 0;
                }

                iKeyless.widget.Rotator.rotate().defer(5000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tagwise - Is this Prototype and not jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you need to do this

```
iKeyless.widget.Rotator.rotate.defer(5000);
```

instead of this

```
iKeyless.widget.Rotator.rotate().defer(5000);
```

[Source:](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/defer) When you write rotate(), you execute the function `rotate` and then execute `defer`.  When you write rotate.defer() you are getting the function `rotate`, and using the method `defer` that is defined on Function.

Also, if this is jQuery, how do you have defer defined? I'm not sure jQuery provides a defer function.  If this is Prototype, I don't think defer takes any arguments.  Perhaps you want [`delay`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/delay).  Delay takes a time in seconds, so you'd want (assuming 5 seconds, not 5000 seconds):

```
iKeyless.widget.Rotator.rotate.delay(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know the defer, but what I read is this:

> Schedules the function to run as soon as the interpreter is idle.

But that doesn't mean that it doesn't actually do it. The function rotate calls itself, again and again. Not linear, but inside itself, so you'll never end the 'top' calling rotate.

This would mean infinite recursion, and so I'm not surprised at that error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `defer()` but you're calling `rotate()` inside your rotate method which is where the recursion is coming from.  Perhaps leveraging something like `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is a way to work around your issue?